# Long POST time fixed by Linux. Why?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dvd

I was recently given a Gateway MT6723 laptop (Intel 2310 1.43 MHz, about 8 years old) that had a two minute POST time and the DVD wouldn't work.  After trying to reinstall the factory Vista factory settings, it still had those two problems.

I really wanted to put XP on it and just use it as an arcade, but since the DVD wouldn't work, I install Mint 17.1 from a USB.  Suddenly, not only was the post time normal, but the DVD worked!

Since the DVD was working now, I decided to try to install XP.  The installer told me the first disk was damaged, so I cleaned it and that seemed to work until it told me that there is no hard drive.  Ok, maybe for some reason Linux is effecting this, so I tried to use DBAN to totally erase the hard drive.  But, now the DVD won't work again and the POST was back to about 2 minutes.  Nothing was installed, but somehow being exposed to Windows screwed everything up.  At least that is what appears to be happening

I reinstalled Mint and now POST is normal and the DVD is working.  This whole situation mystifies me.  Can anyone give some insight?

Right now, I plan on keeping Mint and just use WINE to run the older programs designed for XP.

Comment: You realize that without a reproducible test case, you're asking for speculation here, right? I mean, you can't go back and make the system fail at will again.

Comment: I suppose that I could try to install XP again.  If that is the general consensus, I'll do that.  It doesn't take long to reinstall Mint.

Comment: It seems you are asking a question about Windows. Or am I misunderstanding you? To put it another way, you don't actually have a Linux problem, you have a Windows problem?

Comment: Faheem, it looks like you are probably right.

Comment: What makes you think that the two minutes are the POST time, and not the Windows startup time? Does your laptop boot with UEFI or legacy BIOS (probably legacy given the age, but please confirm)?